# C# marshaling C++ functions

Tags: c#, c++, struct, marshalling, hikvision

I am trying to use the Hikvision SDK https://www.hikvision.com/en/support/download/sdk/
My current goal is to open the door (trigger an output) with the intercom outdoor station.

I managed to do the login (NET_DVR_LoginV40) and display the outdoor station's camera feed.

My next step would be to open the door. For this I need to call the NET_DVR_RemoteControl function  passing in among others the struct of NET_DVR_Control_GateWay.

Now when doing this it does not work it returns error 17 which is apparently:

> Parameter error. Input or output parameters in the SDK API is NULL, or
> the value or format of the parameters does not match with the
> requirement.

So it is practically 100% that something is iffy in my C# code. But I have no idea what it is and as far as I know this is quite impossible to pinpoint easily if you are not an expert at this (I am not)

**The dll import for the function:**

```
[DllImport(@"..\bin\HCNetSDK.dll")]
public static extern bool NET_DVR_RemoteControl(int lUserID, uint dwCommand, IntPtr lpInBuffer, uint dwInBufferSize);
```

**The struct for the parameter of the previous function:**

```
 [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct NET_DVR_Control_GateWay
        {
            public uint dwSize;
            public uint dwGatewayIndex;
            public byte byCommand;
            public byte byLockType;
            public UInt16 wLockID;
            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1)]
            public byte[] byControlSrc;
            public byte byControlType;
            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1)]
            public byte[] byRes3;
            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1)]
            public byte[] byPassword;
            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 108, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1)]
            public byte[] byRes2;
            public void Init()
            {
                byRes3 = new byte[64];
                byRes2 = new byte[108];
            }
        }
```

**My method for the door opening:**

```
 private void button_Door1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_Control_GateWay gateWay = new CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_Control_GateWay();
            gateWay.Init();
            gateWay.dwSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(gateWay);
            gateWay.dwGatewayIndex = 1;
            gateWay.byCommand =1; //opening command
            gateWay.byLockType =  0 ; //this is a normal lock not a smart lock
            gateWay.wLockID = 0; //this is 0 because I want to use the door station's output
            gateWay.byControlSrc =  new byte[] {123} ; // this needs to be something, but doesn't matter what
            gateWay.byControlType =  1 ; //this needs to be 1 or 2 but does not matter which
            //gateWay.byPassword = ; this is not needed because the LockType is 0
            IntPtr ptrStruData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)gateWay.dwSize);
            var dd = CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_RemoteControl(lUserID, 16009, ptrStruData, gateWay.dwSize);
           
            MessageBox.Show(dd.ToString() + CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_GetLastError().ToString() + "\n" + gateWay.dwSize.ToString() + "\n" + "ptrStruData:" + ptrStruData.ToString());
        }
```

[According to the documentation the function looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RchKm.png)

[And the struct is defined as such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFz89.png)

So according to my knowledge I have done the definition and import correctly.

I would appreciate if someone could set me in the right direction as I have never worked with C#, c++ interoperation before and at this point I have no idea how to go forward, how could I debug, how could I determine the problem in my code.

I have tried contacting the manufacturer about this issue, but they cannot help directly with my code, and from their perspective everything is working as it should as I get back the error that it is me who is the cause for the issue.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate some memory with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, you do not copy your `gateWay` structure into that memory, you pass the pointer to the allocated memory to `NET_DVR_RemoteControl` so that it sees [random garbage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?view=net-5.0#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_AllocHGlobal_System_Int32_), and then you do not free the allocated memory so that it leaks.

You could have fixed it by [copying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr?view=net-5.0#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_StructureToPtr__1___0_System_IntPtr_System_Boolean_) `gateWay` into the allocated memory and then [freeing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal?view=net-5.0#system-runtime-interopservices-marshal-freehglobal(system-intptr)) it after the call.

Instead, however, it is better to let the marshaller do its job:

```cs
[DllImport(HIKVISION_LIBRARY, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool NET_DVR_RemoteControl(int lUserID, int dwCommand, [In] ref NET_DVR_CONTROL_GATEWAY lpInBuffer, int dwInBufferSize);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct NET_DVR_CONTROL_GATEWAY
{
    public int dwSize;
    public int dwGatewayIndex;
    public byte byCommand;
    public byte byLockType;
    public short wLockID;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = NAME_LEN)]
    public string byControlSrc;

    public byte byControlType;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public byte[] byRes3;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = PASSWD_LEN)]
    public string byPassword;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 108)]
    public byte[] byRes2;
}
```

```cs
var gateWay = new NET_DVR_CONTROL_GATEWAY()
{
    dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf<NET_DVR_CONTROL_GATEWAY>(),
    dwGatewayIndex = 1,
    byCommand = 1,
    byLockType = 0,
    wLockID = 0,
    byControlType = 1
};

var dd = NET_DVR_RemoteControl(lUserID, 16009, ref gateWay, gateWay.dwSize);
```

Comment: Well sir, you are a true scholar!

This has solved the problem it is working now. I cannot express how grateful I am. One little addition for anyone who will try this in the future, include byControlSrc in your gateWay with any string otherwise it will return error 23 (not supported command).